# Using dplyr and group_by to calculate number of repetition for a value

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, group-by, subset

I have a dataset which includes **seller_ID**, **product_ID** and **year** the product was sold, and I am trying to find the year that one seller had maximum sold product and the specific number of sold in that year for each individual seller. Here is an example of data

```
seller_ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4)
Product_ID <- c(1000,1000,1005,1004,1005,1003,1010,
                1000,1001,1019,1017)
year <- c(2015,2016,2015,2020,2020,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2005)

data<- data.frame(seller_ID,Product_ID,year)

       seller_ID Product_ID year
1          1       1000 2015
2          1       1000 2016
3          1       1005 2015
4          2       1004 2020
5          2       1005 2020
6          3       1003 2000
7          4       1010 2000
8          4       1000 2001
9          4       1001 2001
10         4       1019 2001
11         4       1017 2005
```

so the ideal result would be:

```
    seller_ID   Max_sold_num_year     Max_year
1         1                 2           2015
2         2                 2           2020
3         3                 1           2000
4         4                 3           2001
```

I tried the approach I explained below and it worked ...

```
df_temp<- data %>% 
  group_by(seller_ID, year) %>% 
  summarize(Sold_in_Year=length(Product_ID))


unique_seller=unique(data$seller_ID)


ID_list=c()
Max_list=c()
Max_Sold_Year=c()
j=1

for (ID in unique_seller) {
  df_temp_2<- subset(df_temp, df_temp$seller_ID==ID)
  Max_year<- subset(df_temp_2,df_temp_2$Sold_in_Year==max(df_temp_2$Sold_in_Year))
  
  if (nrow(Max_year)>1){
    
    ID_list[j]<-Max_year[1,1]
    Max_Sold_Year[j]<-Max_year[1,2]
    Max_list[j]<-Max_year[1,3]
    j<-j+1
  }
  
  else {
    
    ID_list[j]<-Max_year[1,1]
    Max_Sold_Year[j]<-Max_year[1,2]
    Max_list[j]<-Max_year[1,3]
    j<-j+1
  }
}
#changing above list to dataframe

mm=length(ID_list)
df_test_list<- data.frame(seller_ID=numeric(mm), Max_sold_num_year=numeric(mm),Max_year=numeric(mm))

for (i in 1:mm){
  
  df_test_list$seller_ID[i] <- ID_list[[i]]
  df_test_list$Max_sold_num_year[i] <- Max_list[[i]]
  df_test_list$Max_year[i] <- Max_Sold_Year[[i]]
}
```

however, due to subsetting each time and using for loop this approach is kind of slow for a large dataset. Do you have any suggestions on how I can improve my code? is there any other way that I can calculate the desired result without using for loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```r
library(dplyr)

seller_ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4)
Product_ID <- c(1000,1000,1005,1004,1005,1003,1010,
                1000,1001,1019,1017)
year <- c(2015,2016,2015,2020,2020,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2005)

data<- data.frame(seller_ID,Product_ID,year)

data %>% 
  dplyr::count(seller_ID, year) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(seller_ID) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(n == max(n)) %>% 
  dplyr::rename(Max_sold_num_year = n, Max_year = year)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   seller_ID [4]
#>   seller_ID Max_year Max_sold_num_year
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>             <int>
#> 1         1     2015                 2
#> 2         2     2020                 2
#> 3         3     2000                 1
#> 4         4     2001                 3
```

And thanks to the comment by @yung_febreze this could be achieved even shorter with

```r
data %>% 
  dplyr::count(seller_ID, year) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(seller_ID) %>%
  dplyr::top_n(1)
```

**EDIT** In case of duplicated maximum values one can add `dplyr::top_n(1, wt = year)` which filters for the latest (or maximum) year:

```r
data %>% 
  dplyr::count(seller_ID, year) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(seller_ID) %>% 
  dplyr::top_n(1, wt = n) %>% 
  dplyr::top_n(1, wt = year) %>% 
  dplyr::rename(Max_sold_num_year = n, Max_year = year)
```

Comment: can you please tell me where exactly you used "tidyverse" package functions? what I see is basically "dplyr" functions. please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @RoozbehYousefnejad Just made an edit. Actually it's only dplyr.

Comment: ```dplyr::top_n(1)``` also does the same thing as ```dplyr::filter(n == max(n))``` in this case

Comment: @yung_febreze. Thanks for the tip. I knew there was an even shorter way ... (:

Comment: @stefan, I tried the approach explained above and for some reason, the old method (for loop) I sued returns data frame with 12789 rows while the approach you explained above returns 17884 rows. I check the number of unique ID on your approach and it retuned 12789 numbers, so it seems that for some reason your approach doesn't create a group properly. Any suggestions or comments regarding it?

Comment: @stefan, actually I dug more into it and found the reason. It seems that in some cases where we have the same maximum number of sold products in two different years, this approach will list both values; however, I am interested only in the latest result. For example:   if seller 1212 sells a maximum 6 products in both 2013 and 2015, this approach will list both while I am interested only in the laster one which is 6 products in 2015. Is there any way to modify your code to fix this?

Comment: @Roozbeh_you. Aw. Always these duplicates. (; But this can be  easily fixed. In that case we have to add another line of code to filter for the latest year. I just made an edit. Best S.